# Is a Library a project or a C# source code file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, libraries

Certains things in Visual Studio tend to be equal to something. E.g. a Project when compiled results in an assembly (exe file and dll file) being generated. Hence, `Project equals to an Assembly` when the project is compiled.

What is a Library in Visual Studio, is it a Project, a single C# source file or a combination of C# source files? Perhaps it is something I did not list.

Comment: *usually*, a library is synonymous with a dll, assembly, and project; the main significance of a library being: you can't *execute it directly*, but rather: it contains (compiled) code that *another* project can make use of

Comment: @MarcGravell When the topic of a Library comes up, a Class Library project is ussually part of the discussion. Is "Library" exclusive to only a Class Library Project (dll file of a Class Library Project)? Or is any Project (dll file of any Project) a Library?

Comment: well, the last "l" in "dll" is for "library", so... pretty much: sure (at least, in the context of .NET which is distributed in dll files)

Comment: @MarcGravell "sure" as in "Library" is exclusive to only a Class Library Project (dll file of a Class Library Project)? No other project template has Library in its template name.

Comment: If you run the C# compiler (`csc.exe`) from the command line, and you want to build a DLL assembly, you include the `/target:library` command line argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library project is a loose collection of files which contain namespaces and classes which then can and are compiled into a dll for *linking* into other projects, such as an executable.

The project and resulting dll are considered as a generically termed *library* regardless of whether it is code in a project or a dll.

Comment: Ok, so the "project" is a Library and the "dll file" generated from compiling the project is also a Library. But does that only apply to a c# project, based on project template "Class Library Project"? or is a project based on any "project template" a Library?

Comment: Yes, within Visual Studio eco-system, libraries, class libraries are the same but just a horse of a different color. All of them have the *intent* on being a library. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up megaMan :)  Relevant to what you said above though. Are you saying that the term "Library" only applies (equals/equates) to a project based on the project template "Class Library"?

Comment: yes, for there is the ability to hold *resources* non compiled items, as embedded items in a library. But there is no "Embeded Library" templates.

Comment: "But there is no 'Embeded Library' templates." But isn't "class library" an embedded library template. I mean "library" is part of the project template name. Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant in that statement.

Comment: The are all libraries, regardless of name. A Library is just code or resources which can be pulled into an exe or app. That is all.